# Php Regular expression to find question mark in an array

Tags: php

I want to check whether the array value contains '?' or not. If yes, then the character succeeding question mark has to be extracted. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// Assume the Url to be localhost/demo/index.php?set=1
$path = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (strpos($path[2], '?') !== false) {
echo "found";
}
?>
```

How to achieve the same using preg_match?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that is in the php documentation and this specific question will probably not help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array or a string? In arrays its not like characters are bunched together. Assuming you meant a string you can try

```
<?php

$haystack="testata?basdasd";
$needle="?";

 $pos = strpos($haystack,$needle);
 if($pos!==FALSE && $haystack[$post+1]!="")
  echo $haystack[$pos+1];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **`in_array()`**.. Pretty faster than regex

```
<?php

$a = array('1','?','3');
$needle = '?';
if(in_array($needle,$a))
{
    echo $needle;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your question means if there is a '?' character in a string, in an array:

Without Regular Expressions:

```
<?php
   for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
     if (strpos($array[$i], '?') !== false) {
       // you found your item, use the $i index and break the loop
     }
   }
?>
```

With Regular Expressions:

```
<?php
   for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
     if (preg_match('/\?/', $array[$i])) {
       // you found your item, use the $i index and break the loop
     }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$storedText = [];

Foreach($arrray as $a){
   $postion = strpos($a,"?");

   If($position !== false){
      $succeedingText = substr($a,$position);
      $storedText[] = $succeedingText;
   }

}
```

Than the $storedText is an array with all the text succeding the ? Of all value that contains an ?